# how to create an exact copy of a form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I want to create the same form multiple times in a project, but I can't find out how...
I tried to copy the code, to copy and paste and rename .Designer.vb and .vb files in the project, but none of these worked.

I know that there a few similar questions, but I keep getting errors...

Is it possible to give me a step by step guide on how to do this?

Comment: `Dim frm As New frmToCopy()` //  `frm.Show()`  You can have multiple *instances* of the same form...it is also how you should create and show *all* forms

Comment: Is there any way to save these forms after their creation?

I mean you can create a copy of a form while the application is running, but if you stop it do you still have this copy saved somewhere?
Or they are deleted when the application stops?

Comment: save them into the project?  Why would you need to when they are *identical*?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to create multiple pages for a fairy tale, I want them all to have the same pattern... So instead of creating 30 different forms that looks exactly the same, I can create just one and multiply it...

Comment: Are you against modifying a new instance in code by  adding the image and words for the current page?

Comment: I believe that duplicating the same form could be far more convinient...

Answer (score 1):

Whether you should do this or not is a separate question but to do what you ask you will need to copy 3 files for the form to the other project folder Assuming the form is called Form1 the three files you need will be named as follows:

Form1.Designer.vb
Form1.resx
Form1.vb

Once you have all three files copied to the other project just use the button in the solution explorer to show all files and then include these files in your second project.  If there are any errors they will be due to missing references so check that but you should be all good.